# div background style in joomla index.php not working

Tags: php, css, templates, joomla, background

I've developed a joomla template which has this code in its css file:

```
#slide-1{
   background:  url(../slide-1-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

which is working as expected: I have the background image in my home page. Now I would like to change this based on the image choice made in the admin part of the template by reading a variable. 
At top of my index.php file before html document information starts I have:

```
$slide6bgimg = $this->params->get('slide6bgimg', '');
```

and further to use it in the html doc definition inside the head tag as:

```
<style>
     #slide-1{
          background:  url(<?php echo $slide6bgimg;?>) 0 0 no-repeat;
     }
</style>
```

this in practice failed. I then tried to test it without php code with my relative path altered:

```
#slide-1{
     background:  url("slide-1-bg.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

which is also a fail. My index.php is in the same folder (template folder) where my image is, so that must not be a problem as long as I understand. Also, before the code of slide-1, I have color code for css reading out of my template admin (by php echo the variable) and it is working correctly. Only the background image is no way working. I tried every possible way I could think of and searched the google but no chance. There must be something I absolutely don't know!

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image url should be relative to the location of the css file and not the index.php file.

Comment: Even if the above <style> is loaded in top (<head>) of the index.php file?

Comment: When the css is in stylesheet, the urls are relative to the location of that stylesheet

Comment: Well sorry if my english is not enough clear: if you look at the post, I just started with the url related to image in my css file. My question is when the style is on top of index.php in joomla, where I echo the value for the css properties. Thank you.